# How does a team agent acess the certificate section from the provisioning portal?

Tags: ios, provisioning

I'm an iOS dev (and team admin) and am setting up a build machine.
Rather than set up the build machine using my provisioning profiles and putting my certificate in the key chain I  thought I'd set it up using the team agent's profiles and certificates  (as the build machine will not belong to me for just my personal build use).

I've just logged into the Apple developer site as the agent (I have his un/pw) but there is no  provisioning portal menu that appears like there is when I am logged into the site as myself.  This seems to be because the agent isn't actually  registered in the iOS development program (which seems strange, how did  they manage to become the agent for the iOS dev team and have certificates generated without being so?).

Anyway, when I am logged onto the developer site as myself if I look  at the team provisioning profile or the apple push profile I can see that these  contain the agent's certificate. But as the developer site doesn't offer a portal page when logged in as  the agent, how did the agent's certificate get created in the first  place and how can I now access sutff such as associated keys to download and install in the  build machine's keychain, or as the agent approve a CSR for the build machine?

Thanks

Comment: This agent belongs to your team?

Comment: Yes, but how is "belongs" defined exactly? I mean how can they be the agent and not belong to the team?